# Return type vararg?

Tags: java

I have a method like:

```
void foo(int x, Grok... groks);
```

There's no way to define a method that returns a type of varargs, right? Ideally I want an additional util method:

```
foo(25, new Grok(), new Grok(), generateMoreGroks());

public Grok... generateMoreGroks() {
    return new Grok[] {
        new Grok(), new Grok(), new Grok() };
}
```

right?

---- More info --------------

The issue with the above is that we can't mix a few Grok instances allocated there with an array of Groks:

```
 "new Grok(), new Grok(), generateMoreGroks());"
```

and I don't think that's legal, unless you could define a method to return a type of vararg (I guess).

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do,

```
Grok[] generateMoreGroks() {
```

If a method takes a varargs parameter, it is the same as taking an array.

Now you need to overload foo to allow it to take some Grok instances, and the rest as varargs,

```
foo(int x, Grok... rest)
foo(int x, Grok g1, Grok... rest)
foo(int x, Grok g1, Grok g2, Grok... rest)
foo(int x, Grok g1, Grok g2, Grok g3, Grok... rest)
```

Where foo methods are like,

```
foo(int x, Grok g1, Grok... rest) {
     Grok[] groks = new Grok[rest.length + 1];
     groks[0] = g1;
     System.arrayCopy(rest, 0, groks, 1, rest.length);
     foo(x, groks);
}
```

This is a bit ugly.

Comment: Hi yeah but I can't mix an array with some Grok instances in the varargs parameter (as in the call to foo() above). I can either only supply an array, or individual Grok instances. But not both?

Comment: Ah bummer, too bad the language doesn't handle that. Ok I think this is the best option to support somethin like this, thanks for your help.

Comment: You could reverse the parameters, like this: `foo(int x, Grok groks[], Grok... moreGroks)` and call it like `foo(25, generateMoreGroks(), new Grok(), new Grok())`.

Comment: Yeah for sure, we still have to do the array copy ourselves (not a big deal), was just hoping the language could support this because it makes our code look a little cleaner.

Comment: One problem with this approach is you will have to keep overloading foo for different number of fixed `Grok`s that the caller wants to specify. I would have defined `foo(int, Grok... groks)` and leave it to the caller to construct a single array of `Grok`s.

Answer (score 5):

No there isn't...  but change the function signature and that will work just fine.

```
public Grok[] generateMoreGroks() {
    return new Grok[] {
        new Grok(), new Grok(), new Grok() };
}
```

Comment: Right but I can't mix a few 'new Grok()' instances with the array returned by generateMoreGroks() in the call to foo().